# PUSH values using REST APi in Flask,GET result

Tags: python, flask

For example I would like to push 2 and 10 as int using my REST Api and get a result. I need to have both client and server running as .py files. This is my server file which interest me most, because I know how to push some values into the server and I already did, what I would like to dois to count rectangle area having 2 and 10 using GET.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)
tasks = [
 {
 
 'first_value':2,
 'second_value': 10,
 },]


@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
 return jsonify({'area_rect': tasks})
if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Where exactly should I multiply 2x10 to get the result?

Comment: replace your "return jsonify({'area_rect': tasks})"  statement with the return of the multiplied value.....

Comment: Can I call it like that?     return jsonify({'area_rect': 'first_value'/'second_value'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you. This way you would return a list of all the calculated Areas of the posted rectangles :D.

```
def area(x):
    return x["first_value"] * x["second_value"]    

@app.route("/tasks")
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify([area(task) for task in tasks])
```

Comment: how to call first value of json and second value of json? (tasks)

Comment: See above :D your not calling json values as you have your rectangle information saved in a list of dictonaries. Getting dict values to a key is done by dict["key"].